# Having trouble with my sql connection code

Tags: java, mysql

I can't seem to make this work:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class connect {
    public static Connection sqlconnect;
    public static Connection OpenDB()
    {
        String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "";

        if (sqlconnect == null){
            try{
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                sqlconnect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(database, user, password);
                System.out.print("Connection Passed");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print("Connection Failed!");
            }
        }
        return sqlconnect;
}
```

}

I've tried many codes that I see online and none of them work, every time I use this code there aren't any errors popping up, but it won't print or show me if I am connected in the database. I am using this as an object in a button.

I called the object by using this:

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    connect c = new connect();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ? I feel like `password=""` can be a cause.

Comment: So are you saying that you don't see either `Connected Passed` _or_ `Connection Failed!`?  Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: If you can't see either Connection Passed or Connection Failed in your console, it means literaly that your `sqlconnect` is not null.

Comment: @msagala I see, sorry I am new at this, I removed the if statement and still no output.

Comment: if so, then put your entire code. if once it entered your try block, it will rather print one of those in your console. If not, I think you have error in other part of your code.

Comment: @Mritunjay I have no password set in my localhost wamp server

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Yes I can't see it, I removed the IF statement and still nothing. I used the debugger, but nothing shows.

Comment: @Ken Y-N added it, but still nothing shows-up.

Comment: @msagala that is my entire code, and I use that as an object in a button.

Comment: I guess that your method is not called properly. try to give us more information about what you are doing.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Updated my code

Comment: try to call your connection like this `connect.OpenDB();` since it is static

Comment: I've just noticed that `btnSubmitActionPerformed()` doesn't directly call `OpenDB()` - does the constructor for `class connect` actually do so? (And making `sqlconnect` and `OpenDB` `static` makes little sense, but that's another problem...)

Comment: @msagala it shows an error.

Comment: @Ken Y-N I just got it from the net so I have no idea. Should I make a constructor?

Comment: OK, I'm done here. Please study some kind of introductory course to Java and Java debugging tools, as you are not actually calling the function you have asked us to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstExample {

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename";


   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  


      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);


      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "select * from tablename";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


      while(rs.next()){


         String first = rs.getString(1);
         String last = rs.getString(2);



         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
}
```

copy the above code and add `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin` jar file . and run it eclipse. but make sure that database name and username , password details are valid.

Comment: I am using netbeans

Comment: it runs even on netbeans also.